# C# Typo Generator Algorithm

Tags: c#, .net, web-applications

I have a requirement where i need to get all possible typos(if not all most) that can occur for a possible word. For example (word : user). User can type "usre" or "yser" something like that.

Currently i don't have anything in mind as to where i start. If anybody has already faced the similar situation and came with the solution, it would be helpful if you can help get kick start

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Generate every permutation, except the word itself. https://www.khanacademy.org/math/precalculus/prob-comb/combinatorics-precalc/v/permutation-formula

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto When I say permutation, it would be every permutation using the letters of a given word, not all possible combinations of a 4 letter word. `area` is not a permutation of `user`. Permutations is a start to solve a problem like this. If you go based off of the length of the word (which is valid) then ANY word with equal length is technically a typo...in fact, any string that is NOT the word is a typo. like `userq` The scope of the problem is too large.

Comment: This is unsolvable in a practical manner without some stated restrictions on what constitutes a "typo".

Comment: @JabariDash How can we get *yser* from *user* using permutation? I get your point that permutation will give us typos, but that is one of the many types of typos that can occur.

Comment: @JabariDash - So, going with the *permutation* idea, if a user types "listen", is that the word they meant to type, or is it a typo of "silent"?

Comment: This could include a) pressing the wrong adjacent key, b) pressing the wrong adjacent key and pressing the correct key, either before or after, c) pressing a correct key more than once, d) skipping a key, e) pressing two correct keys out of order, and f) misspelling. And probably lots more. SwiftKey had this figured out pretty well so Microsoft bought them for like $100 billion.

Comment: Also, failure to capitalize or capitalizing a word that shouldn't be, like Thanks in Advance. :)

Comment: Are you trying to correct a word or get every permutation of it?

Comment: *"Currently I don't have anything in mind as to where I start"*. Then you're at the wrong place, at least for now. You should do some research, give something a try, and come back when you get stuck on a specific issue.

Comment: @Faruq That is my point. That Permutations is a good start, but the problem is too broad.

Comment: @RufusL Again, permutations is a good start. It covers a small subset of typos, namely misspelling the target word. But, the OP is just too broad.

Comment: @JabariDash I agree, this is far too broad and complex, but I disagree that permutations are a good start. This is because 99% of the typos I make are from either typing an incorrect (adjacent) character, adding an additional character (hitting 2 keys at once), leaving out a character (not pressing hard enough - going too fast), or simply not knowing the correct spelling of the word; but rarely occur from swapping two valid characters. But that's just my opinion. :)

Comment: @RufusL I agree, in practice, I hit adjacent keys far more often than I misspell. I mention permutations because there is a known algorithm (which is relatively easy to implement) for attacking that small part of the issue. But, yes, creating a production quality text processor would probably favor adjacent keys over swapped characters when identifying typos. That however, is not an elementary level programming challenge.

Comment: @JabariDash Agreed! And as i think about it, there are a few "subset" permutations that I type, like `uo` instead of `ou`, or `ei` instead of `ie`, and various permutations of `ing`, so I've changed my mind a little. Good discussion!

Comment: Finding permutation of typo it's counter productive. What would you do with that info ? it's not useful for anything. At best you are trying to check if the word is correctly written or not. Then it's again wrong to do it like that. Simple dictionary check with word suggestion.

Comment: @Franck yes, dictionary check is for sure a good idea. But how do you determine the suggestion? How do you find a "similar" valid word? I think that's what we were talking about...

Comment: @Franck Yes, I agree with Rufus, dictionary look up is useful for determining whether or not the word is valid or not. You could also use a Trie to do that in less memory. I think that's what Faruq's answer hints at. But yes, what constitutes similar? Word length? x% of letters in common? Key adjacency? An upper case in the wrong location (like tHis)? Define typo...

Comment: @RufusL you have word completion (which will give you correction suggest too) with any version of office. vba can do it very easily. I am pretty sure there are other possible solution. Google probably have one too.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a wild idea.

Create a graph using the layout of a *QWERTY* keyboard (assuming that is the layout the user will be using), where every *key* will be a node and every node will be connected to the adjacent keys/nodes. For instance, the the node `s` will be connected with `q`,`w`,`e`,`a`,`d`,`z`,`x` and `c`.

Now, for a given word, substitute one or more letter with all neighboring nodes from the graph. So, the word *user* can produce u*w*er, u*a*er, u*d*er and so on.

I hope this will help you.